# i used socketio in my nodejs app and my server slows down sometimes and sometimes it does not respond and sometimes it automatically reloads

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, socket.io, real-time

i am building a Management App with Nodejs, Expressjs, MongoDB and Reactjs. i used socketio for realtime-ness. before using socektio, my app works fine i.e. it responds every request i made to my Nodejs API. when i used socketio, it slows down i.e. sometimes it does not respond to my queries or sometimes it automatically reloads and sends request from Client to Server. it does not show any errors. please help me to solve this issue. i have to deploy this system by next week and not getting how to solve this.

i made a separate file socket.js in which

```
let io;

module.exports = {
  init: httpServer => {
    io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, { wsEngine: "ws" });
    return io;
  },
  getIO: () => {
    if (!io) {
      throw new Error("Socket is not initialized");
    }
    return io;
  }
};
```

in my nodejs starting app index.js, i use this like this.

```
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/QuickResponse")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB...");

    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    const server = app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`)
    );

    const io = require("./socket").init(server);

    io.on("connection", socket => {
      console.log("New client connected");

      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Client is disconnected");
      });
    });
```

and whenever i want to use this in my other files, i use like this,

```
const io = require("../socket");
const complaint = await Complaint.findById(req.params.id);
  if (!complaint)
    return res.status(404).send("Complaint with given ID was not found.");

  const admin = await Admin.findOne().limit(1);

  complaint.assignedTo = {
    _id: admin._id
  };
  complaint.assigned = false;

  await complaint.save();

  io.getIO().emit("complaints", {
    action: "drop",
    complaint: complaint
  });

  res.status(200).send("You have successfully dropped responsibility");
```

and on the frontend i have used socketio-client.
where i use like this.

```
import openSocket from "socket.io-client";
const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:5000", { reconnection: true });
    socket.on("complaints", data => {
      if (data.action === "new complaint") {
        this.createNewComplaint(data.complaint);
        toast.info(
          `New Complaint has been registered with title "${
            data.complaint.title
          }"`
        );});
```

i don't want my server to slow down or do not respond to my queries

Comment: One thing I can guess is, you need to to check is the payload(the message) size limitations for socketIO. I see you are emitting complete `complaint` object.

Comment: yes i am. because i want the whole object. i just showed u the one example. i have socket.emit() in many files bcz i want realtime-ness.

Comment: socket.io is using debug module. can you set DEBUG=socket.io* before starting of  server app and add this log to message.

Comment: i cant understand what you are saying